# Using Kestrel with named pipes?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I was wondering if anyone knew how to get Kestrel to listen on named pipes such that the only modifications to an already existing program that is using HTTPClient should be changing the connection string from http://localhost to net.pipe://localhost  The nearest that I could find to using Kestrel with named pipes is https://github.com/atlascode/Kestrel.Transport.Streams , but that's a more extensive modification to the program than I'm trying to accomplish.  I have also seen some hints about libuv with named pipes, but nothing completely explaining how to accomplish what I'm looking for.  The target environments that the application runs on are W10 for development and Azure for deployment.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Geoff